# WPF XAML Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyName, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm going through a book Mastering WPF and I'm trying to make one simple view with a converter work using MVVM pattern:
[image: W]

When I try to run it, I get this exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '12' and line position '44'.'
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Kulagin.Mastering WPF.Converters, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

I don't understand why it tries to find a file `Kulagin.Mastering WPF.Converters`. It's not a file, only a namespace.

In the file `BitRateView.xaml` if I remove `Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Sixteen}` from RadioButton controls:
[image]

The exception doesn't get thrown and application runs but isn't working as intended because there's no converter hooked anymore. I read through all the code but I can't find what is causing this exception. All the references seem fine and it should work, but it doesn't.

Here's the solution with the exception: https://github.com/KulaGGin/MasteringWPF

All the other projects and classes are there because the author is showing how to build a framework and I'm following it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kulagin.Mastering WPF.Converters` is a DLL

In the project Kulagin.Mastering WPF, see in the section Reference,  the converters are in another Dll, so you have to reference it, because you are using a converter

it misses the reference to `Kulagin.Mastering WPF.Converters`

Add it..

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Who knows how many hours it would take me to find this.